# How to insert values into a table from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, relational-theory

I have three tables

```
students table 
------------------------------------  
id(PK, A_I)  |  student_name | nationality

teachers table
------------------------------------
id(PK, A_I)  |  teacher_name |  email

classroom table
----------------------
id(PK, A_I)   | date   | teacher_id(FK to teachers.id)  |  student_id(FK to students.id)
```

If I was given teacher's name (`david` for example) and student_id (`7` for example) and asked to insert the `teacher_id` into the `classroom` table based on the `id` in the `teachers` table, I would do :

```
insert into classroom (date, teacher_id, student_id)
select '2014-07-08', id, 7
from teachers
where teacher_name = 'david';
```

Now, what if I was not given the student's id directly and given only the name of the student? Suppose I was given teacher's name 'david' and student's name 'sam'. How do I get the `teacher_id` from `teachers` table and also `student_id` from the `students` table and insert both into the `classroom` table based on their respective names?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would write the query like this

```
insert into classroom (date, teacher_id, student_id)
select '2014-07-08', t.id, s.id
from teachers t,students s
where t.teacher_name = 'david'
and s.student_name = 'sam';
```

Be careful. This is a Cartesian product. Another way to approach this is

```
select teacher_id into @tid from teachers where teacher_name = 'david';
select student_id into @sid from students where student_name = 'sam';
insert into classroom (date, teacher_id, student_id) values ('2014-07-08',@tid,@sid);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, can i use inner join here?

Comment: No need for an `INNER JOIN` since `teachers` and `students` have no foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way you can do this is using sub queries:

```
 INSERT INTO classroom(teacher_id,student_id)
 VALUES ((SELECT id FROM students WHERE s_name='sam'),
 (SELECT id FROM teacher WHERE t_name='david'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO newtable(value1, value2, value3) 
SELECT value1N, value2N, value3N,(SELECT valueN4 FROM secondtable WHERE id='1') 
FROM firsttable WHERE id='1');
```

This will put the result form firsttable `value1N, value2N, value3N` and the result from secondtable `valueN4`

### Result:

- first table---`|username|password |name|`---(has 3 values, but we use
  one)
- second table---`|id_number|Adress|tel|`---(has 3 values, we use
  all)
- newtable after query will be fill 
  ---`|id_number|Adress|tel|username|`-----(we get 4 values: 3 from second table and 1 from first table: